# bypass the ac compressor with shorter serpentime belt

Tags: ac, kia, serpentine-belt, soul

I have a 2020 Kia Soul LX 2.0 liter 4  cylinder I'm trying to bypass the AC compressor due to its failure what size belt do I need to use

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is the compressor allowing the pulley to turn or not? Most faulty compressor still work as an idler pulley, allowing the serpentine belt to run. However, if the compressor pulley (bearing) seized and preventing the serp belt from operating, you can always search for an unusable compressor matching yours from salvage yards and replace your damaged one. Just be sure the pulley turns freely as all you need is the pulley and bearing to run; the compressor itself doesn't interfere with pulley rotation unless you power up the compressor. Just leave the electrical connector disconnected.